# asked him something/asked something of him

Tags: meaning

> (a) I asked him something.
>
> (b) I asked something of him.
>
> (c) I asked something from him.

Which of the above could be used for the following situations:

> 1. I asked him a question
> 2. I asked a favor of him
> 3. I asked him to give me something

Answer (score 1):

You have it right.

> (a) I asked him something. = 1. I asked him a question.
>
> (b) I asked something of him. = 2. I asked a favor of him.
>
> (c) I asked [for] something from him. = 3. I asked him to give me something.

Well done!